# How to make a check once per day

Tags: django, web

In my models, I care about how long each object has been in the database and flagged as active. so if the model is active for more than a number of days, it should give an alarm icon in every place the name of the object appears.

At the moment I am calculating the dates difference (today - creation date) for all the objects in every GET request. But I don't think it is the right way to do this because I will have thousands of objects when the website is over.

What is the professional way to do such checks?
Thank you

Comment: I think you're looking for a [celery task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) but its not clear to me exactly what you want..

Comment: Actually it is not clear to me too. I mean I don't know what techniques in web development solve this issue.
I thought about creating a property in the model tells if the object is old and update this value every day automatically.

Comment: That would be very error prone, it would be much better if possible to delete objects as they're not needed or filter out those that you actually don't care about at all before you start performing your queries, celery would allow you to run a task on the actual server without relying on requests but again, im not sure what you're looking for

Comment: I can't delete any object. I just want to give an alarm when an object is old. to do this, I need to check the object every time I display it (in a list of objects, as a search result or in its details) so is it right to make the calculations every time I display any object?

If I am showing all the objects in a list, then I have to calculate the date differences for every object in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [celery periodic task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Make a Celery Schedule like this:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-monday-morning': {
       'task': 'tasks.check_active_objects',
       'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0),  # Will run everyday midnight
   },
```

}

And add this method to tasks.py to make the objects flagged which are created before threshold time:

```
@app.task
def check_active_objects():
    current_time = datetime.now()
    threshold_time = current_time - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    YourModel.objects.filter(creation_date__lte = threshold_time).update(alarm_flag=True)  # Make a field active for alarm
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's isolate the function that does the check, that you call on each GET request. Let's name that function `run_checks()`

What `run_checks()` should do is, run on your whole database, or a subset of it, e.g. from date X to date Y, depending on your business. The other thing it should do if possible: it should persist the state of the check. E.g. if you are *flagging* these with icons, you can have a `MyModel.flagged = True/False` or `MyModel.flagged = NULL/date`.

Persisting the state of the report allows you to take shortcuts in the next run, e.g. where you can run the check only on non-flagged rows, e.g. `rows_to_check = MyModel.objects.exclude(flagged=True)`

Now once you have that check function:

- You can make it into a `./manage.py run_checks` [custom Django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) and call it periodically from **cron** (with a @daily command),
- Or, schedule it periodically on a **task queue** (Celery, [django-background-task](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-background-task), python-rq, etc)